# Authenticate windows server user in Python / C

Tags: python, c, windows

I want to authenticate an user in Python(2.6 or 2.7) / C code .

I have to create a simple authentication module which will take `username and password` as input and will validate user (like [`PAM`](http://www.pythondiary.com/reviews/python-pamV0.1.4.html) module for `UNIX`).

Any way to do it ?

Comment: You want to authenticate against Active Directory/LDAP?

Comment: @Mark \ I  just want to authenticate user like winscp does before starting session

Comment: @Mark please bear me I am newbie to windows

Comment: PYAD perhaps? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyad.

Comment: I guess you are trying to do an authentication from SAM or NTLM. Though I am not much aware of that. But this interested me and after a littile bit of research reached here. See if this helps you: http://www.ejabberd.im/node/55

Comment: thanks @SomanDubey..But this will create lots of dependencies. I am looking for pure python (2.6 or external module compatible with it )  solution.. I will try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?, to authenticates local user, for example:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from os import environ
from ctypes import windll, byref, POINTER, FormatError, GetLastError
from ctypes.wintypes import (
  LPCWSTR, WCHAR, DWORD, HANDLE, BOOL
)

MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH = 15
LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8
LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0

CloseHandle = windll.Kernel32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = [HANDLE]
CloseHandle.restype = BOOL

LogonUser = windll.Advapi32.LogonUserW
LogonUser.argtypes = [LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, DWORD, DWORD, POINTER(HANDLE)]
LogonUser.restype = BOOL

if __name__ == '__main__':
  username = 'MyUsername'
  password = 'MyPassword'

  token = HANDLE()
  status = LogonUser(username,
                     environ['COMPUTERNAME'],
                     password,
                     LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT,
                     LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                     byref(token))
  error = GetLastError()

  if status:
    print('OK, successes')
    CloseHandle(token)
  else:
    print(FormatError(error))
```

Comment: #BHS I dont have access to windows machine now ...will give this a try by tomorrow..thanks for your great help and time

Comment: @Pilot mmm works fine to me, have you changed `MyUsername` and `MyPassword` to yours?

Comment: #BHS yes I did..which windows are you using?

Comment: @Pilot Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: @Pilot OK, I did small modification for better error message, you can check what is the cause.

Comment: `Logon Failure : the user has not been granted the requested logon tupe at this computer`

Comment: @Pilot This is properly wrong login type flag. I update it now, you can also check different flags from [`LogonType`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser).

Comment: Thumbs up Master..thanks for bearing my shits...I just wanna check if same work on windows server machine..